# puts + .inspect doesn't display has_many attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got these two classes:

```
class UserResult < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :survey_result
  has_many :phone_usages, class_name: 'PhoneUsage'
  validates :user_uuid, presence: true
  validates :period_start, presence: true
  validates :period_end, presence: true
end
```

and

```
class PhoneUsage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user_result, class_name: 'UserResult', foreign_key: 'user_result_id'
  validates :start_time, presence: true
  validates :end_time, presence: true
end
```

note `UserResult` - `PhoneUsage` relation.

I fetched `UserResult` and eagerly loaded `:phone_usages`:

```
@user_result = UserResult.includes(:phone_usages).where(user_uuid: params[:user_uuid])
```

and if I loop over `@user_result` I can see `:phone_usages` are present.
But if I do:

`puts @user_result.inspect`

I don't have `:phone_usages` displayed:

```
<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<UserResult id: 1, survey_result_id: 1, user_uuid: "8147646e-2a47-4a0e-b907-8808ee5c5b94", period_start: "2019-04-11 22:01:55", period_end: "2019-04-11 22:01:59">, #<UserResult id: 2, survey_result_id: 2, user_uuid: "8147646e-2a47-4a0e-b907-8808ee5c5b94", period_start: "2019-04-11 22:05:38", period_end: "2019-04-11 22:05:56">]>
```

note there are no `:phone_usages`.

I tried other methods for fetching the `:phone_usages`

Afer trying `puts @user_result.to_json` I got:

```
{"id"=>1, "survey_result_id"=>1, "user_uuid"=>"8147646e-2a47-4a0e-b907-8808ee5c5b94", "period_start"=>Thu, 11 Apr 2019 22:01:55 UTC +00:00, "period_end"=>Thu, 11 Apr 2019 22:01:59 UTC +00:00}
{"id"=>2, "survey_result_id"=>2, "user_uuid"=>"8147646e-2a47-4a0e-b907-8808ee5c5b94", "period_start"=>Thu, 11 Apr 2019 22:05:38 UTC +00:00, "period_end"=>Thu, 11 Apr 2019 22:05:56 UTC +00:00}
```

trying `puts @user_result.phone_usages.inspect` gave me an error:
`NoMethodError (undefined method 'phone_usages' for #<UserResult::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000055e9144fb250>)`

Comment: puts @user_result.as_json have you tried this?

Comment: @Noriel still the same

Comment: if you want to inspect associated objects , you can try `@user_result.phone_usages.inspect`

Comment: @Nandhini error 500 NoMethodError, added in the original post

Comment: hey @NemanjaZunic, I updated my answer. give it a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`includes` does not mean you see the `phone_usages` inside the users. It's more like, if you call `phone_usages` on a user, this does not trigger a query, it's already loaded. Now, if you want to inspect the `phone_usages` passing through your users you can do

```
puts @user_result.flat_map(&:phone_usages).inspect
```

Note that `phone_usages` is an association you call on a single user, not on a user relation. In fact my example could be written more explicitly

```
puts @user_result.map { |user| user.phone_usages }.flatten.inspect
```

If you want to create a JSON with the phone usages included try

```
puts @user_result.as_json(include: :phone_usages)
```

Note that you still need the `includes` if you don't want to trigger one query for each user